# Alignment of enumerate

Tags: enumerate

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[1.]
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item Factor $2^{15}-1=3$
\item Find an integer 
\item Find an integer
\item Find an integer
\end{enumerate}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Then how to align this list?

Thanks.

Comment: `description` has a different alignment. Use `enumerate` instead. But if you want to personalize the item labels, use the package as cited by @Ian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two `enumerate` environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
\item
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item Factor $2^{15}-1=3$
\item Find an integer
\item Find an integer
\item Find an integer
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: enumerate]